# Ionic2 product mode in android not work properly

Tags: ionic2

recently I finished my app with ionic2 and about to build, when I use ionic build --release --prod ,it can work well in ios but not in android.when I build android a package or just use ionic run android with product mode,I can run my app and get the main page.But wherever I click next,the screen will go white like get a white mask and every thing hardly seen,but in console no thing goes wrong.here is some screenshot:

first in

[image]

do some click and go white

[image]

could someone help me or did some one get same situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i solved it by remove my setting in variables.scss, by reducing $colors setting to less than 20 makes my app work well in prod mode, more detail in [ionic issues](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12474)